# C# ADS Beckhoff Write 2D Array throw Exception "Unable to marshal object"

Tags: c#, .net, exception, ads

I tried to write a 2D array of strings via `AdsClient.WriteAny()`, but it did not work.

Here is the C# code

```cs
public bool WriteToPLC(string VarName, object VarValue)
{
     
    try
    {
        int hVar = tcclient.CreateVariableHandle(VarName);
        tcclient.WriteAny(hVar, VarValue);
        tcclient.DeleteVariableHandle(hVar);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is the class code

```cs
public class BackDriveModel
{
    public string ParamName { get; set; }

    public string[,] PathList = new string[4, 2];
}
```

Here is the PLC
[PLC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9cLT.png)